# Como centralizar e posicionar lado a lado duas imagens? html css

Tags: html, css, imagem, margin

[image: como quero q fique]

HTML:

```
<div id="ladoalado"><img src="imgs/login.png"><img src="imgs/cadastro.png"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#ladoalado{
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Imagem do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vc pode usar por exemplo `display:flex` para isso.

Veja como fica no exemplo, deixei os comentário no código.

```css
#ladoalado{
    display: flex; /* coloca as imagens uma ao lado da outra */
    justify-content: center; /* alinha as imagens no centro da tela */
}
```

```html
<div id="ladoalado"><img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100"><img src="https://unsplash.it/101/100"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando a reposta do Hugocsl, use a propriedade `justify-content: space-around;`

`justify-content: space-around;` cria espaços iguais antes, entre e depois dos seus elementos HTML.

Veja no exemplo abaixo...

```css
#ladoalado{
   display:flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="ladoalado"><img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100"><img src="https://unsplash.it/101/100"></div>
```